# Método bind no reasigna el This al contexto indicado

Tags: reactjs

Estoy utilizando unas funciones que se encargan de medir la distancia entre dos coordenadas.
Por cuestiones del proyecto estas funciones se encuentran en un componente padre que por medio de props llevo al componente hijo.

El problema es que, aunque haya utilizado el metodo `bind()` para reasignar el contexto del operador `this` al componente hijo, las funciones siguen trabajando con el contexto del componente padre y su respectivo estado. ¿Cuál es el error?

**Componente padre**

```
class App extends React.Component{
    // Función en caso de éxito de la promesa getCurrentPosition
    succes = async(pos) =>{
      // Guardado de las coordenadas en el State 
      await this.setState({
          currentUbicationLatitude: pos.coords.latitude,
          currentUbicationLongitude: pos.coords.longitude,
      })
      // Medición de las distancias y guardado en el State
      this.setState({
        kmDistance:  this.getKilometros(this.state.currentUbicationLatitude, this.state.currentUbicationLongitude, this.state.destinoDistancia.latitude, this.state.destinoDistancia.longitude)
      })
    }
    
    // Promesa que devuelve la ubicación del usuario
    getDistance(succes){
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(succes);
    } 
}
```

**JSX del componente padre** (`Distance` es el componente hijo)

```
<Distance distanceFunction={this.getDistance} getKilometros={this.getKilometros} succesDistance={this.succes}/>
```

**Componente hijo**

```
export default class Distance extends React.Component{
    succes = this.props.succesDistance.bind(this); 
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.distanceFunction(this.succes)
    }
}
```

Como ven, utilizo el método `bind()` para ajustar el operador 'this' al contexto del componente hijo. Pero este sigue utilizando el contexto del componente padre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las [funciones flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) son funciones especiales que se introdujeron en ES6 y no tienen "noción" del `this`. Sino que el `this` hacen referencia al contexto(scope) en el que están definidas.

Deberías usar métodos de clase para añadir el `bind`.

Tal como dice la documentación no son apropiadas para el uso del `bind`, `call`, `apply`.

```javascript
class App extends React.Component {
    // Función en caso de éxito de la promesa getCurrentPosition
    async succes(pos){
      // Guardado de las coordenadas en el State 
      await this.setState({
          currentUbicationLatitude: pos.coords.latitude,
          currentUbicationLongitude: pos.coords.longitude,
      })
      // Medición de las distancias y guardado en el State
      this.setState({
        kmDistance:  this.getKilometros(this.state.currentUbicationLatitude, this.state.currentUbicationLongitude, this.state.destinoDistancia.latitude, this.state.destinoDistancia.longitude)
      })
    }
    
    // Promesa que devuelve la ubicación del usuario
    getDistance(succes){
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(succes);
    } 
}
```

Te recomiendo sacar la lógica de calcular de las distancias en un objeto o función externa. Así "desacoplas" el cálculo de la distancia del componente.